# sql - get max(date) before set date

Tags: sql

I have table of results

```
2013-01-28 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-01-29 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-01-30 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-01-31 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-02-04 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-02-05 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
2013-02-06 00:00:00 0001101 669.170000
```

If I have a date that is not in this result set, I need to get first date before for second column, to return third column

For example, for date 2013-02-03, I do not have result, so I need to get first before
from 2013-01-31

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Do you have a table of all available dates anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your above result set is in tbl1 and you want to result and for  SQL server dbms

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tbl1
WHERE  Date <= '2013-02-03' 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Why not `Date <= '2013-02-03'`?

Comment: This depends on the RDBMS op is using. For instance, MySQL doesn't have a `TOP`